# Resuming apt-get upgrade after starting a new shell to examine the situation

Tags: apt

At start my situation was similar to this:
[A new version of configuration file /etc/default/grub is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113732/a-new-version-of-configuration-file-etc-default-grub-is-available-but-the-vers#)

I don't know why but I thought It would be like solving a git conflict so I choose **"start a new shell to examine the situation"**.

I am not able to re-start `apt-get upgrade`.

```
root@mygroup-03074302:/# sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo: unable to resolve host mygroup-03074302
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

This is a brand new VM I have not modified grub personally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're still in the shell you have started to examine the situation, just exit it and it'll return you to the (currently running) package installation process.

Comment: I am pretty sure I exited with CTRL-D and it closed the whole terminal. Trying to reproduce your claim it did work though as you describe.