# How can I transfer my sshd_config changes to the new file during a Debian upgrade?

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, openssh, sshd

During a Debian upgrade, a user could be prompted to update their `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:
https://superuser.com/questions/1638779/automatic-yess-to-linux-update-upgrade

The selected answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113745) suggests a manual review of the differences and a manual transfer of changes to the new file.

Can this process be automated, after the installation completes by transferring existing changes **only** to the new file?

For example if I choose to keep the existing config file, is there a function that merges it with the default file `/usr/share/openssh/sshd_config`?